# Actual Image of a triangle in complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Let ABC be an acute-angled triangle. Let the altitudes from the vertices A, B, C meet the circumcircle at P, Q, R whose corresponding complex numbers are $z_1,z_2$ & $z_3$ respectively. If $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}$  is purely imaginary, then angle A is

(A) $\frac{\pi}{2}$

(B) $\frac{\pi}{3}$

(C) $\frac{\pi}{4}$

(D) None of the above

I have already solved this problem and the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$

My solution is provided .

But some student asked me how the ACTUAL IMAGE looks in reality. Can some body helped me with the actual image which corresponds to this problem. My image is just a representative image

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with drawing a really accurate image? Just draw a circle, inscribe a triangle with a 45 degree angle, and draw the altitudes.

Comment: It is unclear what 'actual' mwans in this context. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Actually I wanted to show ABC, $x_1,z_2,z_3$ so that one can understand the concept of solving problem using clock wise and anti clockwise direction, hence an accurate image will helpful

Comment: Actual means any acute angled triangle which follows the above criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share a synthetic solution that utilizes some properties of orthocenters. Since you primarily asked for an accurate diagram, I will share that as well.

[image: Example Triangle]

It is a well known orthocenter reflection property that $P,Q,R$ are the reflections of $X$ about the sides of the triangle. If $Q'$ is the reflection of $Q$ about $BC$, then we have
$$\angle XPQ=\angle PXQ'$$
Since $Q'$ is the reflection of $X$ about $AC$ and then about $BC$, another property about paired reflections about lines tells us that
$$\angle XCQ'=2\angle ACB$$
$$\angle XQ'C=\angle Q'XC=\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle ACB$$
Hence,
$$\angle PXC=\angle PXQ'+\angle Q'XC$$
$$\angle PXC=\angle XPQ+\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle ACB$$
Some angle chasing yields that
$$\angle ABC=\angle PXC$$
$$\angle ABC=\angle XPQ+\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle ACB$$
$$\angle XPQ=\angle ABC+\angle ACB-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Using symmetrical reasoning, we also get that
$$\angle XPR=\angle ACB+\angle ABC-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Adding these two equations gives
$$\angle QPR=2(\pi-\angle BAC)-\pi$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi-2\angle BAC$$
$$2\angle BAC=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\angle BAC=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

Comment: Actually, there is a much simpler solution that uses the property of inscribed angles to show that $\angle APQ=\angle ABQ=\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle BAC=\angle ACR=\angle APR$. Hence, $\angle QPR=\pi-2\angle BAC\implies \angle BAC=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $\text{ABC}$ be an acute-angled triangle. Let the altitudes from the vertices $\text{A}$, $\text{B}$, $\text{C}$ meet the circumcircle at $\text{P}$, $\text{Q}$, $\text{R}$ whose corresponding complex numbers are $z_1$,$z_2$ and $z_3$, respectively. Then $\frac{z_3−z_1}{z_2−z_1}$ is purely imaginary if and only if $\angle \text{A}=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

*Proof.* Since $\text{ABC}$ is an acute-angled triangle, the orthocentre $\text{X}$ must be inside  $\triangle \text{ABC}$, and points $\text{P, Q, R}$ must be on the inferior arcs $\text{BC, CA, AB}$, respectively.

Note that $$\begin{cases}\angle \text{RPA}=\angle \text{RCA}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle \text{A},\\
\angle \text{QPA}= \angle \text{QBA} =\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle \text{A}.\end{cases}$$
Thus,
$ \angle \text{QPR}=\angle \text{RPA}+\angle\text{QPA}=\pi-2\angle \text{A}$. Hence, $\angle \text{A}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ iff $\angle \text{QPR}=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Note that
$\angle \text{QPR}=\text{Arg} \left(\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\right)$, but $\angle \text{QPR}<\pi$, so that $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}$ is purely imaginary iff $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}=ai$ for some $a>0$ iff $\angle \text{QPR}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Therefore, $\angle \text{A}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ iff $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}$ is purely imaginary.